# Suppress pip root user warning in github actions/setup-python

Tags: pip, github-actions

When using a *self-hosted runner in AWS EC2* the following warning persists:

> WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

To mitigate the problem I set the environment variable `PIP_ROOT_USER_ACTION=ignore` on the job's level per `env`-key in the yaml file, as well as per a bash-step exporting the environment variable to `$GITHUB_ENV` - and neither worked so far.
I tried to follow up on the matter and found [this post](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/513) to be the only other question documented so far. But the suggestions posted are not working.
Any help to suppress this warning is much appriciated as it is not possible to use a non-root user as explained [here](https://github.com/machulav/ec2-github-runner/issues/64#issuecomment-907688504).

Code (snippet) in use:

```
run_tests:
  name: Run Testing Suite
  runs-on: self-hosted
  steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set-up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: '3.8'
      env:
        PIP_ROOT_USER_ACTION: ignore
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the `env` on the top level of the YML file? [either between the `on:` and the `jobs:`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#defining-environment-variables-for-a-single-workflow) or [as an `environment:` variable before `steps:`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#using-the-vars-context-to-access-configuration-variable-values)?

Comment: I suppose the problem results somehow from the fact, that we are using a custom runner (vague feeling, no argument for it). Your supposed solutions unfortunately do not work.

Comment: self-hosted runner or [running jobs inside a container](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/running-jobs-in-a-container#example-running-a-job-within-a-container)? have you tried to add a step that `echo $PIP_ROOT_USER_ACTION`?

Comment: We are starting self-hosted runners (`runs-on: self-hosted`) in a VPC in AWS Cloud. The `echo` returns that the env var was set successfully. Really confuses me.